# unregonized command line option '--showme:link' error

Tags: command-line, bash, compiling, bashrc

I ma attempting to install OpenFOAM on ubuntu 14.04 on a virtualbox. However, when I run the script to compile the source, I receive a

```
cc: error: unrecognized command line option '--showme:link'
```

I have been following the guide located here (http://www.openfoam.com/download/install-source.php) in order to install OpenFOAM.

The error occurs when I run the command `source ~/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1606+/etc/bashrc`.

Here is the contents of my .bashrc:

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
```

And the contents of the ~/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1606+/etc/bashrc:

```
#----------------------------------*-sh-*--------------------------------------
# =========                 |
# \\      /  F ield         | OpenFOAM: The Open Source CFD Toolbox
#  \\    /   O peration     |
#   \\  /    A nd           | Copyright (C) 2011-2016 OpenFOAM Foundation
#    \\/     M anipulation  |
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# License
#     This file is part of OpenFOAM.
#
#     OpenFOAM is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#     under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
#     the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
#     (at your option) any later version.
#
#     OpenFOAM is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT
#     ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or
#     FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU General Public License
#     for more details.
#
#     You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#     along with OpenFOAM.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
#
# File
#     etc/bashrc
#
# Description
#     Startup file for OpenFOAM
#     Sourced from ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc
#     Should be usable by any POSIX-compliant shell (eg, ksh)
#
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

export WM_PROJECT=OpenFOAM
export WM_PROJECT_VERSION=v1606+

################################################################################
# USER EDITABLE PART: Changes made here may be lost with the next upgrade
#
# either set $FOAM_INST_DIR before sourcing this file or set
# 'foamInstall' below to where OpenFOAM is installed
#
# Location of the OpenFOAM installation
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
foamInstall=$HOME/$WM_PROJECT
# foamInstall=~$WM_PROJECT
# foamInstall=/opt/$WM_PROJECT
# foamInstall=/usr/local/$WM_PROJECT
#
# END OF (NORMAL) USER EDITABLE PART
################################################################################

#
# These are the defaults for this version which should generally be
# overridden from the prefs.sh file or from command-line specification
#
#- note the location for later use (eg, in job scripts)
: ${FOAM_INST_DIR:=$foamInstall}; export FOAM_INST_DIR

#- Compiler location:
#    WM_COMPILER_TYPE= system | ThirdParty (OpenFOAM)
export WM_COMPILER_TYPE=system

#- Compiler:
#    WM_COMPILER = Gcc | Gcc4[5-9] | Gcc5[1-4] | Gcc61 | Clang | Icc
export WM_COMPILER=Gcc
unset WM_COMPILER_ARCH WM_COMPILER_LIB_ARCH

#- Memory addressing:
#    On a 64bit OS this can be 32bit or 64bit
#    On a 32bit OS addressing is 32bit and this option is not used
#    WM_ARCH_OPTION = 32 | 64
export WM_ARCH_OPTION=64

#- Precision:
#    WM_PRECISION_OPTION = DP | SP
export WM_PRECISION_OPTION=DP

#- Label size:
#    WM_LABEL_SIZE = 32 | 64
export WM_LABEL_SIZE=32

#- Optimised, debug, profiling:
#    WM_COMPILE_OPTION = Opt | Debug | Prof
export WM_COMPILE_OPTION=Opt

#- MPI implementation:
#    WM_MPLIB = SYSTEMOPENMPI | OPENMPI | SYSTEMMPI | MPICH | MPICH-GM | HPMPI
#               | MPI | QSMPI | SGIMPI
export WM_MPLIB=SYSTEMOPENMPI

#- Operating System:
#    WM_OSTYPE = POSIX | ???
export WM_OSTYPE=POSIX

#- Floating-point signal handling:
#    set or unset
export FOAM_SIGFPE=

#- memory initialisation:
#    set or unset
#export FOAM_SETNAN=


################################################################################

# The old dirs to be cleaned from the various environment variables
# - remove anything under top-level directory.
# NB: the WM_PROJECT_INST_DIR might not be identical between versions
foamOldDirs="$FOAM_INST_DIR $WM_PROJECT_SITE $HOME/$WM_PROJECT/$USER"
if [ "$WM_PROJECT_INST_DIR" != "$FOAM_INST_DIR" ]
then
    foamOldDirs="$WM_PROJECT_INST_DIR $foamOldDirs"
fi


# Location of installation
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
export WM_PROJECT_INST_DIR=$FOAM_INST_DIR
export WM_PROJECT_DIR=$WM_PROJECT_INST_DIR/$WM_PROJECT-$WM_PROJECT_VERSION

# Location of third-party software
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
export WM_THIRD_PARTY_DIR=$WM_PROJECT_INST_DIR/ThirdParty-$WM_PROJECT_VERSION

# Location of site-specific templates etc
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
# unset is equivalent to $WM_PROJECT_INST_DIR/site
if [ -d "$WM_PROJECT_SITE" ]
then
    export WM_PROJECT_SITE
else
    unset WM_PROJECT_SITE
fi

# Location of user files
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
export WM_PROJECT_USER_DIR=$HOME/$WM_PROJECT/$USER-$WM_PROJECT_VERSION

# Source initialization functions
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
. $WM_PROJECT_DIR/etc/config.sh/functions

# Add in preset user or site preferences:
_foamSource `$WM_PROJECT_DIR/bin/foamEtcFile prefs.sh`

# Evaluate command-line parameters and record settings for later
# these can be used to set/unset values, or specify alternative pref files
export FOAM_SETTINGS="$@"
_foamEval $@

# Clean standard environment variables (PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, MANPATH)
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
foamClean=$WM_PROJECT_DIR/bin/foamCleanPath

#- Clean PATH
cleaned=`$foamClean "$PATH" "$foamOldDirs"` && PATH="$cleaned"

#- Clean LD_LIBRARY_PATH
cleaned=`$foamClean "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" "$foamOldDirs"` \
    && LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$cleaned"

#- Clean MANPATH
cleaned=`$foamClean "$MANPATH" "$foamOldDirs"` && MANPATH="$cleaned"

export PATH LD_LIBRARY_PATH MANPATH


# Source project setup files
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
_foamSource $WM_PROJECT_DIR/etc/config.sh/settings
_foamSource $WM_PROJECT_DIR/etc/config.sh/aliases


# Source user setup files for optional packages
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
_foamSource `$WM_PROJECT_DIR/bin/foamEtcFile config.sh/mpi`
_foamSource `$WM_PROJECT_DIR/bin/foamEtcFile config.sh/paraview`
_foamSource `$WM_PROJECT_DIR/bin/foamEtcFile config.sh/ensight`
_foamSource `$WM_PROJECT_DIR/bin/foamEtcFile config.sh/gperftools`
_foamSource `$WM_PROJECT_DIR/bin/foamEtcFile config.sh/CGAL`
_foamSource `$WM_PROJECT_DIR/bin/foamEtcFile config.sh/scotch`
_foamSource `$WM_PROJECT_DIR/bin/foamEtcFile config.sh/FFTW`


# Clean environment paths again. Only remove duplicates
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#- Clean PATH
cleaned=`$foamClean "$PATH"` && PATH="$cleaned"

#- Clean LD_LIBRARY_PATH
cleaned=`$foamClean "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"` && LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$cleaned"

#- Clean MANPATH (trailing ':' to find system pages)
cleaned=`$foamClean "$MANPATH"`: && MANPATH="$cleaned"

export PATH LD_LIBRARY_PATH MANPATH

#- Clean LD_PRELOAD
if [ -n "$LD_PRELOAD" ]
then
    cleaned=`$foamClean "$LD_PRELOAD"` && LD_PRELOAD="$cleaned"
    export LD_PRELOAD
fi


# Cleanup environment:
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
unset cleaned foamClean foamInstall foamOldDirs


# Unload initialization functions:
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
. $WM_PROJECT_DIR/etc/config.sh/functions

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is not my first time installing openFOAM. Usually it goes pretty smoothly. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: `--showme:link` looks like an [mpicc](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/mpicc.lam.1.html) option; maybe something is messed up with your MPI environment?

Comment: Could be? I ran sudo apt get install mpich2 so I think that this should take care of it? Maybe I am doing something wrong? Also, as a side comment, how do I create code tags int he comment section?

Comment: I'm not certain about this, but I thought `--showme` was specific to the OpenMPI wrappers (the MPICH2 equivalent is `-show`). Perhaps there are some old environment variables that make OpenFOAM think you are using OpenMPI? Aside: [comment formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Comment: Alright, let me compile openmpi and see if this works

Comment: Ok, So I followed these instructions: http://www.simunano.com/2015/07/how-to-install-openmpi.html
to install openMPI. When I went to run the command, I received that same error

Comment: The instructions you followed appear to install openmpi under $HOME so unless you set your path carefully the system may still be finding mpich2 first. There's rarely a need to install stuff from source, you could have just installed libopenmpi-dev I think. BTW I have no idea if installing openmpi is the right way to solve your issue.

Comment: Hey Steeldriver, installing that package solved the issue

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so it turns out that I needed to run:

```
sudo apt-get install libopenmpi-dev
```

Please refer to the comment posts between me and Steeldriver.

Comment: The problem was solved because when you installed openmpi it became the default (over mpich) which recognized your option `--showme:link`.